# Swift / NSURLSession JSON download / unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift

I am downloading data and handling it using the following code in the `viewDidLoad()`:

```
 NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: "http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=USD")!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

       // Check if data was received successfully
       if error == nil && data != nil {
          do {
             // Convert NSData to Dictionary where keys are of type String, and values are of any type
             let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! [String:AnyObject]
             // Access specific key with value of type String
             let dollarToDollarDict = json["rates"] as! NSDictionary
             SpeedLog.print(dollarToDollarDict)
             let dollarToDollarNSNumber = dollarToDollarDict.valueForKey("EUR")
             let dollarToDollarString = String(dollarToDollarNSNumber)
             SpeedLog.print(dollarToDollarString)
             self.dollarExchangeRateStr = dollarToDollarString
             } catch {
               // Something went wrong
             }
           }
       }).resume()
```

`print(dollarToDollarDict)` prints out the correct Dictionary. `print(dollarToDollarString)` prints out the correct desired String I want to have as: "Optional(1.1303)"

But when I want to use the String in `dollarToDollarString` by having a button pressed, with:

```
func dollarBtnFunc(button: UIButton!) {

    if dollarExchangeRateStr != "" {
        SpeedLog.print("DOLLAR downloaded", dollarExchangeRateStr)            
        let dollarExchangeRateDouble = Double(dollarExchangeRateStr)!
        tableCounterData = ["\(numberInt) $", "\(numberInt * dollarExchangeRateDouble) €"]

    } else if dollarExchangeRateStr == "" {
        SpeedLog.print("DOLLAR not downloaded, Dollar = 0.89")
        tableCounterData = ["\(numberInt) $", "\(numberInt * 0.89) €"]
    }
    currentButton = "dollarBtnFunc"
}
```

I get `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` on `let dollarExchangeRateDouble = Double(dollarExchangeRateStr)!`.

What am I missing? Why is the String `nil`? I have printed the correct value earlier... Why is it not part of my String anymore once I want to use it later? Help is very appreciated.

Comment: it is a print extension. is is just the same as `print()`

Comment: So what does SpeedLog.print("DOLLAR downloaded", dollarExchangeRateStr)   print out exactly?

Comment: `dollarBtnFunc[405]: DOLLAR downloaded Optional(0.88472)`

Comment: Try let dollarExchangeRateDouble = Double(dollarExchangeRateStr!)!

Comment: `Cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type 'String'`

Comment: Then in the download section do this instead: self.dollarExchangeRateStr = dollarToDollarString! (Notice the exclamation mark at the end)

Comment: `Cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type 'String'`

Comment: One final question, what is the type of dollarExchangeRateStr?

Comment: `var dollarExchangeRateStr: String = ""`

Comment: OK, the only thing I can think of is this: self.dollarExchangeRateStr = dollarToDollarString as String!

Comment: thank you for your effort, but it didn't helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in these 2 lines:

```
let dollarToDollarNSNumber = dollarToDollarDict.valueForKey("EUR")
let dollarToDollarString = String(dollarToDollarNSNumber)
```

`dollarToDollarDict.valueForKey("EUR")` returns an optional, so `dollarToDollarNSNumber` is an optional.

Calling the `String` initializer with an optional gives the string `"Optional(...)"` so when you later pass that string to the `Double` initializer it fails because it has letters in it.

You need to unwrap the value you get from `valueForKey` by doing something like this:

```
if let dollarToDollarNSNumber = dollarToDollarDict.valueForKey("EUR") {
    let dollarToDollarString = String(dollarToDollarNSNumber)
    SpeedLog.print(dollarToDollarString)
    self.dollarExchangeRateStr = dollarToDollarString
} else {
    self.dollarExchangeRateStr = ""
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU! not just, that you did it. you explained it, so I understood it... thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I believe your issue lies on the casting of dollarExchangeRateStr to Double. Double("foo") returns an optional which is probably failing on conversion so it's nil, which fails when force unwrapping it.

Change

```
func dollarBtnFunc(button: UIButton!) {

   if let exchangeRateStr = dollarExchangeRateStr {
      SpeedLog.print("DOLLAR downloaded", exchangeRateStr )            
      let dollarExchangeRateDouble = Double(exchangeRateStr ) {
         tableCounterData = ["\(numberInt) $", "\(numberInt * dollarExchangeRateDouble) €"]
      }
      else {
         print("your string to double conversion failed")
      }
   } else if dollarExchangeRateStr == "" {
      SpeedLog.print("DOLLAR not downloaded, Dollar = 0.89")
      tableCounterData = ["\(numberInt) $", "\(numberInt * 0.89) €"]
   }
   currentButton = "dollarBtnFunc"
}
```

it looks from your comments that dollarExchangeRateStr is also an optional, which means that you will need to unwrap that too, note the if let exchangeRateStr = dollarExchangeRateStr

Cheers!